# Delete folder contents and copy new files in batch

Tags: batch-file

Hi I am trying to write a batch file that deletes the contents of a folder and replaces it with different files from another location i have the command that deletes the contents its just adding the copy bit so they work in sequence

```
del "C:\New Folder\*.*
```

Any help appreciated

So this is the copy command i have found any ideas why it doesnt work?

```
xcopy c:\New Folder(2)\*.* c:\New Folder /C /S /D /Y /I
```

Comment: Just like the `del` command deletes files, the `copy` command can be used to copy files. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use quotes, because there are embedded spaces in the directory name:

```
xcopy "c:\New Folder(2)\*.*" "c:\New Folder" /C /S /D /Y /I
```

(I didn't check the options: /C /S etc).